# A relationship between the proof of a renormalizability and gauge fixing conditions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, renormalization, path-integral, gauge

I already know that QCD is renormalizable in several gauges, including the $\xi$ gauge and the background field gauge. That is, the divergence of the quantum effective action is limited by symmetry, and as a result the divergence can be removed by adjusting the coefficients of the original action. However, I feel it odd that the proof of the renormalizability of QCD or some gauge theories as I know it depends on certain gauge fixing conditions. This is because, according to the philosophy of the FP method, a gauge fixing is basically a way to remove the huge non-physical redundancy of gauge degrees of freedom, which in that sense is not an essential component of the theory, and thus these proofs only mean **"*that the theory is renormalizable in that specific gauge*”**. Therefore, I would like to ask two questions:

1. When one show the renormalizability of QCD for example , a particular gauge is chosen. Why is such a "specific gauge dependent" proof widely used? In other word, why is such a gauge dependent proof essential?
2. Is there a proof of renormalizability that does not depend on gauge fixing conditions? In particular, is the theory renormalizable no matter how strange gauge fixing conditions are imposed? (Intuitively, I don't think that's true.）

Answer (score 4):

While OP is right that morally going from one [gauge-fixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing) condition to another is a flow along gauge-orbits, it can in practice be difficult to check that the theory is independent of the gauge-fixing condition: Gauge-fixing in the path-integral may be only partial, and in a quantum average sense, there could be [Gribov ambiguities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gribov_ambiguity), etc.

Moreover, various objects, such as propagators and vertex-correlators, which we use in the [renormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization), explicitly depend on the gauge-fixing condition.

At the formal perturbative level, the [Batalin-Vilkovisky formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism) has been employed to show renormalization and independence of gauge-fixing, see e.g. Ref. 1.

References:

1. S. Weinberg, *Quantum Theory of Fields,* Vol. 2, 1996; Chapters 15 + 17.